# $apply not working when the angular partial is reloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datamaps

I am working on a code including datamaps, angularJS and Javascript. I am using factory to communicate the events between two controllers.

The factory is as follows

```
abc.factory('EventFactory', function () {
return { eventData: ''};   });
```

On the home page partial in one controller, I am updating the factory data as follows

```
.on('mouseover', function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.EventFactory.eventData = 'mouseover';
        });
    })
```

Similarly I am changing the values at mouseout and click events

On another controller I am detecting the change like this

```
$scope.$watch('EventFactory.eventData', function (data) {
    if (data == 'mouseover') {
        //print on console let's say
    }
}, false);
```

Similar handles for mouseout and click.

Everything works fine and every event is detected. But the problem is that when I go to some other partial by clicking and then come back to the same partial of home page, the $apply function doesn't works on any of the events. So the $watch is also not able to detect the change in other controller.

I tried logging on console in the $apply function but, $scope.$apply function doesn't run, which was running perfectly when the partial was loaded the first time.

This seems weird, any idea that what the problem might be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible the element is being redrawn. When do you attach the handler? ngMouseover is probably a better bet and a more 'angular' way of doing this.

Comment: Shouldn't have any dom code in controllers. Create a simple demo of this in plunker using your current code. There really isn't enough shown to sort your problem out

Comment: @GBa .. The elements is actually redrawn what I suppose by datamaps library. The event is attached on markers on the maps generated by datamaps library. I don't think ngMouseover will work on like .on('ng-mouseover', fn()) as datamaps is Javascript based library.